# a single element to use the disabled attribute with

Tags: html, semantic-markup

I am looking a simple html tag that I can use with the `disabled` attribute. Reason: this item is going to be a sub item of a menu and I want to disable the element without any script other than the attribute. I want to prevent click events from ever being raised which is what the `disabled` attribute gives me for free.

I've used anchor tags in the past (which are very easy to style) but they do not support the disabled attribute.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use an `<input type="text" disabled>`. It can be customized easily with css and can have a click event as well.

Comment: I didn't -1 but it doesn't seem semantic. I am leaning towards button more but it come heavily styled by the browser.

Comment: I hate buttons just for that reason... You will need to spend quite a time to make sure it appears the same in different browsers.. Inputs are easier to style imo

Comment: would the person who -1ed care to comment?

Comment: Inputs in the enabled state come with input ability that I do not want to override. I just want click ability and buttons behaviour matches that